# gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: openssl, curl, ubuntu-20.04, gnutls

I am facing this issue when triggering curl to a target application hosted in ubuntu 20.

curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received,Below is the curl version in source.

curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3

Interstingly when i trigger curl from another machine where curl version is different,its working

Working curl version as below.

curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3

I can see that the difference that  in working curl version there is openssl instead of gnutls as source package.

Any reason why gnutls is having handshake issue with ubuntu 20(same curl(7.47) is working against application in ubuntu 16)?

Comment: No..Have already gone through that.This doesnt seems to be a certificate issue.

Comment: Most probably the outdated versions on the Ubuntu 16 (which has been end of life for nearly a year) don't support the encryption on the target server. Update your system to a supported version.